# Just tip when moving an object

Tags: unity

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGV5LPLwMgk

In this tutorial to unity, he makes a river and animates it. But at 1:12
[image] when he moves the object it moves the "waves" in that direction.

But when I try to do it just does the moves at 1:09[image]
I am completely new to the blender I have been stuck on this for ages....
Thank you for your help or any type of advice!

Comment: You mean you can move the waves as show in the video

Comment: What is not clear from the video? Show screenshots of what you tried.

Comment: Try applying scale and rotation for the plane object (Object mode > Ctrl+A menu). If won't work use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload the file and include link here in comments

Answer (score -1):

If i understood is that you need the wave to be moved.

Add a Empty

In the Displacement Modifier tab -> Texture Coordinator -> Object

Below in object select empty. Select the axis which you want to move in my case its Y axis

[image]

Select the empty and move it.

**You get this result**
[image]